# Axis2 with WSDL 2.0 Tutorial

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis

I used Axis2 to create a web service. Axis2 is creating a WSDL which is version 1.1?

How can I create a WSDL version 2.0 for my web service?

Note: I know how to create a web service with Axis2 and Eclipse. So please share a tutorial for a WSDL 2.0 web service.

Comment: I found a tutorial for WSDL 2.0 webservice earlier. I think it will help you. check [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/wsdl/index.html) ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Axis2 added support for WSDL 2.0](http://wso2.com/about/news/axis2-12release/) but it didn't make big news because **WSDL 1.1 is still the de facto standard for describing SOAP web services**.

Having said that, if I remember correctly, you need to add `?wsdl2` to the URL to get back a WSDL 2.0 description of your service. Using `?wsdl` gets you back the WSDL 1.1 version.

Since they have support for WSDL 2.0 it should make sense that [Wsdl2Java](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/CodegenToolReference.html) has also been upgraded to support generating code from WSDL 2.0.

So basically, developing the web service should be the same, it's just that now they have two ways of exposing the web service description.

Comment: ?wsdl2 URL gave the WSDL 2.0 definitions. Thank you so much.