# Rationale behind portType and binding in WSDL

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

In a WSDL we define the operation name, input and output in the portType element; later on in binding we define operation, input and output again. What is the rationale behind this? why define them twice? I understand in binding we define the encodingStyle and other attributes, so what is the need of portType?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WSDL: whats the difference between <binding> and <portType>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511346/wsdl-whats-the-difference-between-binding-and-porttype)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about WSDL 1.1. In WSDL 2.0, you define operations only once, in an *interface* tag.
You should read more about Java libraries' support for WSDL 2.0, for instance: [Axis2 with WSDL 2.0 Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795719/axis2-with-wsdl-2-0-tutorial)